# Search and replace values VFP 9 from two tables

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro, dbf

I have a bdf file for a university project for which I would like to **retrive from another table a value given a matching condition, testing each record** (that they have the same id_number and they do not meet another condition). I've been stuck with this since when doing the replacement it only takes first reference value from the table (not the one that meets the condition).
Those that does not have the condition `1.Mp_id == d2.po` to add the `ship2` in the table of reference, and for the rest that does not meet the condition, to add the `ship2` looking for the paramter `prod_code` to retrieve the `ship2` from the table of reference.

```
CLOSE DATABASES
USE Ruta + "FILE.dbf" IN 0 ALIAS d1
USE Ruta2 + "REFERENCE.dbf" IN 0 ALIAS d2
SELECT d1
ALTER TABLE d1 ADD COLUMN ship c(10) &&create new column to fill in the reference
SELECT d2
GO TOP
DO WHILE !EOF()
  SELECT d1
  REPLACE d1.ship WITH d2.ship2 FOR d1.Mp_id == d2.po
  REPLACE d1.ship WITH d2.ship2 FOR d1.prod_code == d2.prod AND d1.Mp_id != d2.po
  SELECT d2
  SKIP
ENDDO
CLOSE DATABASES ALL
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code.  1) When you do a REPLACE and include a FOR scope, it will replace ALL records in d1 with the d2 value where the FOR expression is TRUE rather than just replacing the single record pointed to in the DO WHILE loop.

Comment: 2) You would be better off using VFP's RELATION between 2 tables as long as the 'Child' table has the appropriate Index set and the 2 tables can meet an expression which equates to TRUE.    You might want to spend some time looking at the free tutorial videos at:   http://www.garfieldhudson.com/freevideos.aspx    Maybe focus on the video named:  Building a Simple Application - Pt. 5  where it shows:  Hightlights of this video are creating temporary relationships between two tables in the data environment,  OR Q&A: Using Related Tables In A Report -- n how to use/setup related tables

Comment: Thanks for the tutorials! I’ve tried the relation method you proposed but it didn’t work, and I couldn’t tell what’s the problem with it. I finally (after three days) managed to do it because I had duplicated values on the conditions, so I created two tables with unique values for the conditional variables I want to cross by. I’ld like to close the question with your answer but didn’t work for me (probably I did something wrong) so I don’t know how should I proceed...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Would you please add some sample data to show us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately 'Giving' you the code does not 'Teach' you anything about how to do this.
The following code was jotted down quickly and not tested, but if you spend some time with the recommended tutorial videos you should be able to tell if the following would work for you and, if not, what might need to be changed.

```
USE Ruta2 + "REFERENCE.dbf" IN 0 ALIAS d2 EXCL  && Open 'Child' table
SELECT D2
INDEX ON po TAG Po  && Index table on po field values
INDEX ON prod TAG Prod  && Index table on prod field values
SET ORDER TO po  && 'Activate' 'child' table Po index

USE Ruta + "FILE.dbf" IN 0 ALIAS d1   && Open 'Parent' table
SELECT D1
ALTER TABLE d1 ADD COLUMN ship c(10) &&create new column to fill in the reference
SET RELATION TO id INTO D2  && set relation such that d1.id = d2.po
REPLACE ALL d1.ship with d2.ship2 FOR !EMPTY(d2.po)

SELECT D2
SET ORDER TO Prod  && 'Activate' 'child' table Prod index
SELECT D1
SET RELATION TO prod_code INTO D2  && set relation such that d1.prod_code = d2.prod
REPLACE ALL d1.ship WITH d2.ship2 FOR !EMPTY(d2.prod) AND d1.Mp_id != d2.po
```

Good Luck

Comment: Although I too appreciate providing teaching basis vs just giving, but as users can learn the basics of SQL is more powerful than what we are accustomed to within VFP world.  Yet some things in VFP are easier than SQL too :)  Cetin's answer appears accurate to a somewhat unclear question posted.  Good comments to clarify what you are trying to do within the code though.

Answer (score 1):

As I said it is not clear what you are trying to do without some sample data and sample output.

You could replace that do while ... enddo with this single update statement:

```
Update d1 ;
    Set ship = d2.ship ;
    from d2 ;
    where d1.Mp_Id == d2.po Or d1.Prod_Code == d2.Prod
```

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explanation, what I meant to do it’s not a simple replace but rather a two condition replacement (non-independent between conditions). I’ll first need to replace by d1.Mp_id and d2.po, but on those that I have a matching on d1.prod_code with d2.prod I’ll replace them with the record on d2.ship that matches this second condition. The problem is that in d2 I have duplicated records for d2.prod with different d2.po. So it would replace all the records that meet the first condition but with the first entry in d2. I’ve solved my issue by eliminating duplicates and creating a d3

Comment: @AR_Domingo, glad you solved it somehow, it was still unclear to me.